# Discord.py - List the user's roles

Tags: python, discord

I want my bot to show me the list of the users roles. If I use `user.roles`, I get this problem:

[image]

Is there a way to let the bot list the roles clean, just like this bot does?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having a list of roles returned. This allows you to iterate over it, picking each individual *attribute* of a role.

For example, the attribute in the second image you've chosen was `.mention`, and the general idea of the code looks like this (adapt it for your own command):

```
@bot.command()
async def roles(...):
    rolelist = [r.mention for r in user.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role]
    roles = ", ".join(rolelist)
```

The list comprehension is getting every role that the user has, excluding `@everyone`.

`roles` is the variable that contains the "beautified" list of roles. And to get the number of roles, just do `len(rolelist)`.

---

**References:**

- [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles)
- [`Guild.default_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.default_role)
- [`Role.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.mention)

Comment: That fixed it, thank you for your great help once again.